# Simplemodal with IE and Iframe

Tags: jquery, explorer, simplemodal

First of all thanks to Eric MArtin for SimpleModal.

I've started using it developing in mac environment. When i loaded to my hosting server and then checked the results in IE, the overlay completely ignores the embedded iframe in my page. It appears as if the iframe has a higher Zindex than anything else on the page, so i checked.  Well firstly simplemodal works fine in Safari and Opera and everything is layered correctly. However in Firefox and IE (using 7 and 8 to check) the iframe is not overlayed.

I also set the zindex property to 9000 to check. Nothing doing. I've dug around simplemoda, the net etc and cannot get any hints on CSS properties that might be used to overcome it.

Any ideas on what is happening anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Hai George,

> HI I Think in IE6 it might be some size or percentage for top and left or zindex issue.In IE7 value should be more than IE6.So change the values. If u specify the top,left or z-index property to popup even if u scroll also the popup will not scroll